# "Too well" or "Good enough": Which goes better In "I didn't know him ......., but I was still upset when he died"?

Tags: grammar

I found this sentence "I didn't know him ......., but I was still upset when he died" so I have to choose between these two answer:

A. too well
B. good enough

According with the results of the test it says that the correct answer is "too well" but I don't understand very well the rule in this specific sentence.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: *Speaking English well doesn't necessarily make you a good speaker.*

Comment: This one was hard for me, too because I was hearing "good" being used in conversations as an adverb. It appears to be, when used as an adverb, "good" is informal or non-standard.

Comment: Note that (unrelated to your sentence) “good/well enough” and “too good” are common.

Comment: I thought also I mean I'm not sure that we use "enough" to express like a certain kind of  negation so that's why I'm confused in here.

Comment: You should ask a different question that addresses that specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Well* is the "adverb form" of *good*, and *good* is an adjective.  People in live speech mix these up all the time, though.

Adjectives can follow the verb *to be*, *to feel*, *to seem*, and a few other verbs, because these types of verbs take complements.

For example, you can say "I am hot" or "I feel sick."  In these situations you can use *good*.  You can also use *well* (e.g. "I am not well.") since a meaning of *well* when it is used as an adjective is "not sick."

*Well* as an adjective is not often used outside of a verb's complement.  For example, it would be far more usual to say "I'm about the release all the patients that are well" than "I'm about to release all the well patients."

This contrived example might help illustrate also:

> A: Did you test all the tools?
>
> B: I did, each one is good.  (You cannot say *well* here because tools are not a thing that get sick)
>
> A: Well, give me one of those good tools.  I need one.  (Etc.)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, **well** is used to describe how much you knew the deceased.

> I didn't know him **too well**
>   I didn't know him **very well**

In your question, you also write

> I don't understand very **good** the rule...

when it should be

> I don't understand very **well** the rule...

since you are talking about your "understanding".

> Having a **good** understanding of *something*, is to understand it **well**.